# MikTex 2.9 Installation Error: File name database capacity exceeded.

Tags: installing, miktex

I am trying a complete installation of MikTex 2.9, using 64 bit installer, from a recently downloaded local package directory, all latest versions.

During installation, I run across this error "File name database capacity exceeded."

Does anybody know a solution to this problem. My complete log file can be viewed at 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7201872/setup-2011-06-29-20-29.txt

Comment: The bug should be fixed: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3329932&group_id=10783&atid=110783. Are you sure you have the newest version of the setup wizard?

Comment: In general such issues are better reported to the bug tracker or mailinglist of the software in question. I'm tending to close this one as "too localized", because it seems to be already fixed in the current MikTeX version.

Comment: Any development with this issue? Could you install MikTeX using the newest installer?

Comment: The installer was the latest version at the time of writing. However I got around the issue by installing the basic version. Not what I wanted, but it worked for me

Comment: According the bug tracker of miktex (http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3329932&group_id=10783&atid=110783) the problem should be fixed. Are you sure that you downloaded the newest version of the setup wizard? Did you used an up-to-date repository?

Comment: the setup wizard I was using was 2.9.3959, I see now there is a 2.9.4193       .....my bad :(

Comment: @Terence: No issue, I will merge it with the other similar question.

Comment: This error is definitely not fiex in the installer from the website downloaded today. I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: MikTeX has many problems, that's why I stop using it. Use TeX Live 2010 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem. But you can install a basic version firstly, and the needed package can be installed automatically during the document being compiled.

Answer (score 2):

I got same problem.  I was installing the "full" package in:

C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9

(which is the automatic suggestion of the installation program), instead I tried

C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTeX 2.9

i.e. I was installing the full MikTeX using the 64 bit installer, in the 64 bit Programs folder, and I got the error mentioned above.  But when I installed it in the 32 bit Programs folder instead it all worked smoothly, and I have full functionality.  strange huh?

hope this helps the rest of you!

Comment: For what it's worth, I got this error trying to install MikTex 2.8 on Win7 into either C:\Program Files or C:\Program Files (x86). Then I realized I was installing 2.8 instead of 2.9. 2.9 32-bit installed fine into C:\Program Files (x86). D'OH!

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happend to me, while updating existing 2.9 installation from the newest repository in August 2014. I went around the problem by first updating half of packages and then the other half, because updater allows you to select the packages.