# MikTek Installation error = File name database capacity exceeded

Tags: errors, installing, miktex

Downloaded latest MikTEK July 7,2011.
Attempted 'Complete' installation.
Received the following error:
  "File name database capacity exceeded".
I then attempted 'Basic' installation and was successful.

Comment: Very related (duplicate? same MikTeX version?): [MikTex 2.9 Installation Error: File name database capacity exceeded.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21919/miktex-2-9-installation-error-file-name-database-capacity-exceeded)

Comment: I’m closing this question because it is very old and obsolete in the meantime.