# MikTex Installation Error: File name database capacity exceeded

Tags: miktex

When trying to do a complete intallation of MikTex 2.8 the setup wizard returns the following error:

The operation could not be completed for the following reason:
File name database capacity exceeded.

I know this error was posted about here:

[MikTex 2.9 Installation Error: File name database capacity exceeded.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21919/miktex-2-9-installation-error-file-name-database-capacity-exceeded)

The suggested solution seems to be to use the most recent version of the setup wizard. I want to install MikTex 2.8 (and not 2.9 because 2.9 does not work correctly on my computer), and I am using  setup-2.8.3553.exe. How can I find out if there is a more recent version of the 2.8 setup wizard? There don't seem to be any choices given from the download website, it only provides one setup file to use:

http://miktex.org/2.8/setup

I also know that doing a basic installation instead of a complete installation will work fine, but it would be nice to know if a complete installation is just not possible.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! At the top of the MikTeX 2.8 page you reference is this warning: **MiKTeX 2.8 is considered out-of-date. It is recommended that you install MiKTeX 2.9 instead.** Unsurprisingly, I can't find any `setup*.exe` files for MikTeX 2.8 on the `miktex.org` site. You mention that MikTeX 2.9 doesn't run correctly on your computer. Have you tried downloading and installing TeXLive 2011 instead of MikTeX?

Comment: What is the reason 2.9 does not work on your computer? Are you using Windows 2000? http://miktex.org/2.8/

Comment: @Mico - Thanks for the suggestion, I will give TeXLive a try.

Comment: @Matth - I am using Windows 7. My issue with using 2.9 is described in this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40659/undefined-control-sequence-miktex-2-9-hyper

Comment: @HRC Ok, I see. I support Ulrikes comments, here and in the linked thread. Usually new versions reduce the number of bugs, so if I were in your place I would a) uninstall all TeX distributions, b) install one up-to-date distribution (i.e. MiKTeX 2.9), c) run the update manager and d) create a MWE. If you use MiKTeX, you should also read this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29616/what-is-the-preferable-setup-for-miktex-to-keep-all-packages-up-to-date-easily I once had a silly conflict between packages in the admin folder and in the user folder.

Answer (score 4):

The bug will not be fixed for 2.8: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3427919&group_id=10783&atid=110783. So you should better try to find out how to install and use 2.9. If it doesn't work due to a bug: Make a bug report so that it can be fixed.