# Installing miktex in windows 7

Tags: installing, miktex, windows

I am facing problems in installing MiKTeX. My latest effort gave the following error log:

```
MiKTeX Setup 2.9.3959 Report

Date: Sunday, December 15, 2013
Time: 13:51:21
OS version: Microsoft Windows Vista Home Basic Edition, 64-bit (build 6000)
SystemAdmin: yes
PowerUser: false
SharedSetup: yes
Setup path: C:\as\u\tx\setup-2.9.3959.exe
UserRoots: <none specified>
UserData: <none specified>
UserConfig: <none specified>
CommonRoots: <none specified>
CommonData: <none specified>
CommonConfig: <none specified>

Installation: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9
Loading package database...
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: "C:\as\u\tx\MiKTeX 2.9 Setup"
visiting repository "C:\as\u\tx\MiKTeX 2.9 Setup"...
repository type: local package repository
loading lightweight database...
lightweight database digest: 9ac12380e9220f67d0db4465cc045262
going to install 75722 file(s) (2235 package(s))
problem: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-core-PS.dll does not exist
problem: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-core.dll does not exist
problem: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-packagemanager-PS.dll does not exist
problem: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-packagemanager.dll does not exist
extracting files from 12many.tar.lzma...

***************

extracting files from yplan.cab...
extracting files from yt4pdf.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ytableau.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ytex.cab...
extracting files from zapfchan.cab...
extracting files from zapfding.cab...
extracting files from zed-csp.cab...
extracting files from zefonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from zhmetrics.tar.lzma...

An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\fnamedb.cpp
  source line: 594
  message: File name database capacity exceeded.
  info:
```

Comment: Your log file is saying that your OS is windows vista and not windows 7. I have no idea if miktex should work with this OS but the last time I saw your error message is here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21919/miktex-2-9-installation-error-file-name-database-capacity-exceeded. So I would suggest that you try to install the basic version.

Comment: MikTex 2.9 installs on Windows 7 systems, so this should not be the problem. How did you install? Download the whole installation package first and then install it on your machine?

Comment: BTW Did you install  `Service Pack 2` on windows vista since miktex needs it, http://docs.miktex.org/manual/installing.html#id550800. Follow this screenshots for a 32-bit,complete(all packages) installation. http://www.xm1math.net/doculatex/install_miktex.html.

Comment: My OS is Windows 7, Home Basic. I do not know how and why it shows Vista in log file. Finally the problem is resolved by installing Basic miktex. Thanks!